# Typescript accessing variable with object full of specific objects with period (.) operator

Tags: javascript, interface, typescript, type-declaration

I have a TypeScript interface

```js
interface BookStore {
    books: { [key: string]: Book }
}
```

I can access a single book by it's name like this

```js
BookStore.books['OneGoodBookName']
```

What I need, is to access it with period (.) operator

```js
BookStore.books.OneGoodBookName
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to do it and internet hasn't been helping with this yet. Any ideas if I can do it?

--

**Edit 1: more information**

I can't change the implementation. Only declaration in interface, because it's declaration file for library that other people use in their Javascript code. I don't want to make developers change their JS code when they migrate to TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it like this:

```
var bs: BookStore;
//...
var book = <Book>((<any>bs.books).OneGoodBookName);
```

But in that case you will loose type checks provided by typescript:

Comment: That requires me to change the code in implementation. I can't change implementation, because it's been coded by other developers. I'm creating a TS declaration file for library, that people use in their JS apps. I don't want to force people to change their code when they migrate their JS apps to TS.

Comment: No, it doesn't require a change to the implementation because TypeScript will compile `<Book>((<any>bs.books).OneGoodBookName)` to `bs.books.OneGoodBookName`. It is however rather ugly, so if you're not going to be using index notation it may be easier to just write `interface BookStore { books: any }` and `let book: Book = bs.books.OneGoodBookName`.